# Error in passing 'system:index' values from L8_TOA collection to filter L8_SR collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm new to Google Earth Engine and just starting to learn the tricks. I'm trying to pass 'system:index' values I retrieved from filtering Landsat 8 TOA collection to extract the same images from Landsat 8 Surface Reflectance collection. My code below:

```
var filtSysInd = filtDateCol.aggregate_array('system:index'); //filtDateCol is the filtered Landsat 8 TOA collection
//print('filtSysInd',filtSysInd.get(1));

/*filtSysInd values to replicate the issue
List (7 elements)
0: LC08_075084_20140223
1: LC08_075084_20150125
2: LC08_075084_20151227
3: LC08_075084_20170303
4: LC08_075084_20190104
5: LC08_075084_20200224
6: LC08_075084_20210125*/

var fImage = L8sr.filterBounds(AOI); //L8sr is the filtered Landsat 8 Surface reflectance collection

var counter = ee.List.sequence(0,filtSysInd.length().subtract(1))
//print('counter',counter);
var filtL8sr = ee.ImageCollection(counter.map(function(i){
    var si = filtSysInd.get(i)
    
    //return ee.Image(fImage.filterMetadata('system:index', 'equals',si))
    return ee.Image(fImage.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', si)))
}))
print('filtL8sr=',filtL8sr)
```

The error I get is below:

```
filtL8sr=
ImageCollection (Error)
ImageCollection.fromImages, argument 'images': Invalid type. Expected type: List<Image<unknown bands>>. Actual type: List<ImageCollection>. Actual value: [<ImageCollection>, <ImageCollection>, <ImageCollection>, <ImageCollection>, <ImageCollection>, <ImageCollection>, <ImageCollection>]
```

Could someone help me understand what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

fImage.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', si) produces a collection, not a single image.  Use .first() to get the image.

But far better is to simply filter to the given IDs directly:

```
var filtL8sr = fImage.filter(ee.Filter.inList("system:index", filtSysInd))
```

Comment: Many thanks, this worked very well! I was under the assumption system:index was unique to an image/scene. I thought my code iterated through each System:index and returned a collection at the end of it.